# Apps Script loop to get index of every shape

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

I have defined the google slides presentation and the specific slide therein.

```
var MainSlideSheet = SlidesApp.openByUrl('xxxxxxx');
var Slide1 = MainSlideSheet.getSlides()[0];
```

Now for every shape/ element within that slide, I want to know its index number. How could this be done in Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can get all the page elements with the [getPageElements()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/page#getpageelements) function:

  ```
  var elements = Slide1.getPageElements();
  ```
- To get the object ID of every element in your slide you can use the [getObjectId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/group#getobjectid)
  method inside a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop. Using the latter, you can define an index which will provide the position of the element in the array.

The following code will log the **object ID** of every element and its **index** of the first slide:

```
function myFunction() {
  var MainSlideSheet = SlidesApp.openByUrl('xxxxxxx');
  var Slide1 = MainSlideSheet.getSlides()[0];
  
  var elements = Slide1.getPageElements();
  elements.forEach(
    (el,index)=>
    Logger.log(el.getObjectId(),index)
    // here goes the code that uses el.getObjectId() and/or index
  )
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to find element by ObjectId?